# "value returned is unused" warning when byte-compiling a macro

Tags: emacs, elisp, compiler-warnings, emacs24

Why does byte-compiling the the following produce a warning?

```lisp
(defmacro foomacro (shiftcode)
  `(defun foo (&optional arg)
     (interactive ,(concat shiftcode "p"))
     (message "arg is %i" arg))
  `(defun bar (&optional arg)
     (interactive ,(concat shiftcode "Nenter a number: "))
     (message "arg is %i" arg)))
;; provide backward compatibility for Emacs 22
(if (fboundp 'handle-shift-selection)
    (foomacro "^")
  (foomacro ""))
```

This is the warning I get:

```
$ emacs -Q --batch --eval '(byte-compile-file "foo.el")'

In foomacro:
foo.el:1:21:Warning: value returned from (concat shiftcode "p") is unused
```

If I get rid of `bar`, the warning goes away:

```lisp
(defmacro foomacro (shiftcode)
  `(defun foo (&optional arg)
     (interactive ,(concat shiftcode "p"))
     (message "arg is %i" arg)))
;; provide backward compatibility for Emacs 22
(if (fboundp 'handle-shift-selection)
    (foomacro "^")
  (foomacro ""))
```

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.2.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you forgot to wrap the macro body in a progn:

```
(defmacro foomacro (shiftcode)
  `(progn
     (defun foo (&optional arg)
       (interactive ,(concat shiftcode "p"))
       (message "arg is %i" arg))
     (defun bar (&optional arg)
       (interactive ,(concat shiftcode "Nenter a number: "))
       (message "arg is %i" arg))))
```

Think about how macros work. When you call `(foomacro "...")`, the lisp engine recognizes that `foomacro` is a macro and *expands* it, i.e., calls it on the argument(s) supplied. the return value of the macro is, *as expected*, the *second* `defun` form; while the *first* `defun` form is **discarded**. Then the lisp engine evaluates the return value (which is the *second* `defun` form). Thus in your `progn`-less version only `bar` is defined, not `foo`.

To understand the process, you need to realise that macros are merely "code transformation" tools; they don't really do anything. Thus only their return values are seen by the compiler (or the interpreter).

Comment: Why should I need to wrap the macro body in a `progn`?  The documentation for `defmacro` says `BODY...` indicating that more than one body form is acceptable.  It also matches the documentation for `progn`.

Comment: Hmm...  I guess I don't understand macro expansion like I thought I did.  I've asked a follow-up question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/17093194/712605  Once I understand that, then I should be able to understand how multiple body forms works.