# macro expansion: to quote the body forms or not?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how macro expansion works.  What is the difference in how the elisp interpreter handles these two snippets of code?

```
(defmacro foo (arg)
  (message "arg is: %s" arg))
(foo "bar")
```

and:

```
(defmacro foo (arg)
  `(message "arg is: %s" ,arg))
(foo "bar")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You example may be confusing because

1. `message` both *displays* a message and *returns* it.
2. strings (like "bar") are self-evaluating.

### Instructive Example

```
(defconst zzz 123)
(defmacro zzz1 (arg)
  `(insert (format "arg is: %s" ,arg)))
(defmacro zzz2 (arg)
  (insert (format "arg is: %s" arg)))
```

Evaluate the code above using <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> after each of the 3 forms.

Now evaluate these:

### First version: `(zzz1 zzz)`

The interpreter...

1. calls the macro function of `zzz1`
2. the macro function returns the form `(insert (format "arg is: %s" zzz))`
3. the interpreter evaluates the form, and inserts `"arg is: 123"` into the current buffer, and returns `nil` (seen in the echo area at the bottom)

### Second version: `(zzz2 zzz)`

The interpreter...

1. calls the macro function of `zzz2`
2. the macro function inserts `"arg is: zzz"` in the current buffer and returns `nil`
3. the interpreter evaluates `nil` to `nil` (seen in the echo are at the bottom)

### The bottom line

The most important "take-away" here is that macros are just functions which operate on code before the interpreter (of compiler) kicks in.

These functions take their arguments unevaluated (i.e., in both `zzz1` and `zzz2`, `arg` is `zzz`, not `123`).

They are evaluated like any other lisp function (e.g., they can have macro forms in their bodies; the body is wrapped in an implicit `progn`; &c).

Their return value is evaluated by the interpreter *instead of* the original form.

Comment: It's the two rounds of evaluation that threw me off.  I thought it behaved like the C preprocessor -- that there was only one round of evaluation.  My mistaken mental model was that the macro invocation `(zzz2 zzz)` was replaced by `(insert (format "arg is: %s" zzz))` (the body of the macro but with the args substituted), then evaluated.