# Common Lisp: Why progn is a special form?

Tags: common-lisp

Since Common Lisp's function arguments evaluate in left-to-right order, why wouldn't use an ordinary function:

```
(defun progn2 (&rest body)
  (first (last body)))
```

instead of special form?

Comment: Doesn't `defun` already include an implicit `progn` ? Check the macro expansion of `defun`.

Comment: Both @sds's and @RainerJoswig's answers make important points.  The `values` in @sds's answer is something that you might catch once in a while, and the behavior that @RainerJoswig describes is very important, especially once you start putting macro-based top-level forms in your source;  if these produce more than form that should be treated as top-level, then you need `progn`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is also another feature of `PROGN` which you can't get with a function:

Imagine this code in a file of Common Lisp code:

```
(progn
  (defmacro foo () ))
```

vs.

```
(my-progn
  (defmacro foo () ))
```

With using `PROGN` the compiler will treat the `DEFMACRO` form as a top-level form. That means for example that the compiler notes that there is a macro definition and makes it available in the *compile-time environment*.

Using a function `MY-PROGN`, the compiler won't recognize the `DEFMACRO` form, because it is not at top-level.

Comment: What `top-level-form` means?

Answer (score 24):

[`progn`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm) returns all the values of the last form it evaluates, your function returns just the first one:

```
(progn (values 1 2 3)) 
=>  1, 2, 3
(progn2 (values 1 2 3)) 
=>  1
```

Another critical feature of `progn` (mentioned by Rainer first) is that it keeps all its forms [top-level](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bca.htm), which makes it possible for macros to expand to *multiple* forms (see, e.g., my answer to ["“value returned is unused” warning when byte-compiling a macro"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17078279/850781)).