# Why is do a special form?

Tags: function, clojure, special-form

In Clojure, why is `do` a special form, instead of a function implemented like this?

```
(defn do [& exprs]
  (last exprs))
```

Comment: Almost duplicate, but for CL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137542/common-lisp-why-progn-is-a-special-form, though the answers over there do not apply here.

Comment: Am I wrong, because I can't see how that code can be equivalent to "do"...

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Try it yourself and see. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Basic sequential execution semantics

`fn` (well, `fn*`) actually reuses the logic behind `do`, as do other forms with bodies – `let*`, `letfn*`, `try`. Since there are several of these, it makes sense to have them reuse the basic "evaluate expressions in sequence" logic; and since this in itself is useful to user code outside the context of the more complex special form, it makes sense to expose it as `do`.

Were `fn*` the basic special form instead, sequentially evaluating expressions would involve making a function call – the overhead of that would not be acceptable for this sort of low-level facility.

(On the other hand, replacing the other special forms with macros wrapping their bodies in implicit `do`s wouldn't introduce any overhead. In the context of the Clojure compiler as it stands, however, it wouldn't be a huge win either – on this point at least it's fairly DRY already.)

#### Top-level `do`

Additionally, top-level `do`s are treated specially by the compiler in that

```
(do
  (foo)
  (bar))
```

is equivalent at top level (and only at top level) to

```
(foo)
(bar)
```

– that is, to the individual expressions written out separately. This allows macros to output (code equivalent to) multiple top-level expressions.

It wouldn't be impossible to interpret top-level calls to some special function in this way, but using a special form for this purpose is significantly cleaner.

Comment: I found the BodyExpr class in clojure's source code, where DO is implemented: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/20f3094afd75c404c44bf55b1670f19768fd50cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L5968