# how to make sorted list of the 3 numbers in ascending order in lisp

Tags: list, function, lisp

I am trying to make sorted list of the 3 numbers in ascending order in lisp.
But i got error like "Incorrect number of arguments to if" when compiling and load.

```
(defun order (n1 n2 n3)
     (if (>= n1 n2)
        (progn(progn(if (>= n1 n3) 
            (progn(if (>= n2 n3) (progn(setf max n1) (setf mid n2) (setf min n3))     (progn(setf max n1) (setf mid n3) (setf min n2))))
        (progn(setf max n3) (setf mid n1) (setf min n2))
        )))
         (progn(progn(if (< n1 n3) 
             (progn(if (>= n2 n3) (progn(setf max n2) (setf mid n3) (setf min n1))     (progn(setf max n3) (setf mid n2) (setf min n1))))
        ((setf max n2) (setf mid n1) (setf min n3))
        )))

    ))
    (list min mid max)
)
```

Comment: Genuine curiosity: what do you think `progn` does?

Comment: I think progn is for not making function but I am not sure ....

Comment: downvoted because the code is not indented/formatted in any useful way. It is unreadable.

Comment: -1. please format the code properly and get rid of the extra `progn`s. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17137542/850781 on what `progn` does.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(defun order (min mid max)
  (when (< mid min)
    (rotatef mid min))
  (if (< max min)
      (rotatef max mid min)
      (when (< max mid)
        (rotatef mid max)))
  (list min mid max))
```

First, we assume that the three parameters are already in the right order, if this is not true we change them through the use of [`rotatef`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_rotate.htm#rotatef), a primitive function that swaps two variables or rotate three or more variables.

The first `when` corrects, if necessary, the relative order between `min` and `mid`, swapping them if `mid` is less then `min`.

When we know that `min` is actually less than `mid`, we try to put `max` at the right place in this way:

- first, if it is less then `min`, this means that it is the smaller of the three, and we rotate appropriately the three variables,
- otherwise, it could be between `min` and `mid`, and in this case we swap the `mid` and `max` variables. If it greater or equal to `mid`, no swap must be done and the three variables contain already the values in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than typing randomly and hoping it works, a good approach is to write down, in English, the algorithm you need to implement to order three numbers.  Then, if you are lucky, you can turn it directly into code.

So

To order a, b, c:

- if a <= c

  - if a <= b (a is least, we need to order b and c)

    - if b <= c answer is a b c, else answer is a c b
  - else (a <= c and a > b, we have an order) answer is b a c
- else (a > c)

  - if b <= c (a > c and b <= c so we have an order) answer is b c a
  - else (a > c, b > c, we need to order a and b)

    - if a <= b answer is c a b else answer is c b a

Now turn that into Lisp. remembering that the syntax of `if` is `(if test true-result false-result)` where `true-result` and `false-result` are expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort rendition:

```
(defun order (a b c)
      (when (> a b) (rotatef a b))
      (when (> b c) (rotatef b c))
      (when (> a b) (rotatef a b)) 
      (list a b c))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It is useful you have provided an answer, however, you really need to add more useful details to the answer.  You also risk your answer being downvoted without providing additional supporting details.